# Why doesn't India give shelter to Rohingyas?

Tags: india, myanmar

Bangladesh and India both have borders with Myanmaar.

India has way bigger landmass, financial resource, and manpower. Bangladesh is the most densely populated country in the world.

https://www.reuters.com/article/us-myanmar-rohingya-india/india-using-chilli-sprays-stun-grenades-to-dissuade-rohingya-influx-idUSKCN1BX1BG

Why hasn't India given shelter to Rohingyas?

Comment: Lots of comments deleted. Please don't try to provide an answer to the question with comments. If you would like to answer, please write a real answer which adheres to our quality standards. For more information about what comments should be used for, read [the description of the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 6):

## Official position of India's government

> Seeking to get legal clearance for the deportation plan, the home ministry told the Supreme Court this week it would confidentially provide it with intelligence information showing Rohingya links with Pakistan-based militants.  (*[source](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-myanmar-rohingya-india/india-using-chilli-sprays-stun-grenades-to-dissuade-rohingya-influx-idUSKCN1BX1BG)*)
>
> “Our investigations have revealed that Al Qaeda wants to use India and Bangladesh as their base to start a religious war against Myanmar,” said New Delhi police official Pramod Singh Khuswah. “Clearly they are a threat to our security.”

## Other likely reasons

- Demographics.

  Rohingyas are majority Muslim. India has no desire to have more Muslims living there (it has enough friction with its own Muslim population and Muslim neighbors without adding the need for more). Bangladesh (which is majority Muslim) seems a better place from India's point of view

  Additionally, Rohingyas are ethnically closer to [Benghali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohingya_people) than average Indian populace (though who and what they are seems to be rather convoluted mix). So, India gets to claim "they are your people, they are your problem" to Bangladesh.
- Economics.

  Housing and hosting a large # of refugees is a big economic drain - even more so when the refugees are not homogenuous with native populace (which removes local sources of bootstrapping for refugee individuals AND reduces overall trust capital of the area which reduces economy).

  As such, if India has an option of "we get to pay for hundreds of thousands of refugees, or we punt that on Bangladesh", the preferred option for Indian government is kind of obvious.

Comment: Wiktionary info on the word “Moslem”: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Moslem

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - I fail to see a major difference (neither version is "correct" since they are both transliterations). I updated so all my versions are in sync with each other since I used both.